# How to install something that read excel files in python 3.3

Tags: python, excel

I am new to python and I need to read an excel file in pyscripter. I understand that I should

```
import xrld
```

in Python and then use:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(file_source,file_name +".xlsx"))
```

to open and read the excel file.

However, I just don't understand how to install this module 'xrld'. I have looked on several websites and even on stackoverflow itself, but I just don't understand anything from the explanations that are given. I just don't understand how to install 'easy install' or 'pip' (or understand what these things are in the first place) or understand how to install anything else I need to read an excel file for. So far I installed a file called 'setuptools-36.01.1' from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools which should contain something I could use for running, but I just don't understand what to do.

I thereby must admit (and think it is clear by now) that I am a real noob when it comes to programming or computers in the first place.

Can someone please help me by explaining in plain English what exactly to do in order to read an excel file in python. I have Python 3.3.2 and use Pyscripter to run my simulation.

Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: download the `tar.gz` from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/42/85/25caf967c2d496067489e0bb32df069a8361e1fd96a7e9f35408e56b3aab/xlrd-1.0.0.tar.gz#md5=9a91b688cd4945477ac28187a54f9a3b), unzip it twice and run the `setup.py` using the cmd like so `py setup.py install --user` if I remember correctly

Comment: Also, if the data in excel is in a nice format, then it would be worth seeing if you could read it in using `pandas` and the `pandas.read_excel` method. This would likely be much easier than `xlrd`.

Comment: @Ev.kounis, Thanks to your comment 'twice' it finally worked and I imported the module, but know I am getting an error Errno[13] permission denied. I am using windows. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Eline When do you get the error? Is this a company computer or a personal one?

Comment: it is a personal one. When I type the following line after importing xlrd: 

    book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\eline\Documents\EUR\Master 
    Thesis\Python', 'Example 1.xlsx') 

I get the error that I do not have permission for C:\\Users\eline\Documents\EUR\Master 
    Thesis\Python'

Comment: This would be another question now though, right? The module has been installed. This error means that somehow you do not have right permissions on the specified directory (good luck with the master thesis btw). Sidenote, use `r` before specifying directories like so `r'C:\Users\eline\Documents\EUR\Master Thesis\Python'` and let the slashes be. Can it be that you already have an `'Example 1.xlsx'` in that directory and it is even open?

Comment: Yes this is indeed another question, the module is installed. Thanks for the side note and for wishing me good luck! And within this directory, I indeed have a file called 'example 1.xlsx' (because that is how I say to python to read this file, right?) But I do not have opened this file on my computer right now. How do I check if have the right permissions for this directory? When I look at the properties of the directory it says that I have all the right permissions (at least as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

**EasyInstall (easy_install)** gives you a quick and painless way to install packages remotely by connecting other websites via HTTP.

**Pip** is a package management system used to install and manage software packages, such as those found in the Python Package Index. Pip is a replacement for easy_install.

Since you have installed the setuptools, easy_install will be already present in your system.

So just run `easy_install pip` in the command line to install pip . Then `pip install xlrd` for installing xlrd.

example code:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:/User/myaccount/Book1.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print worksheet
```

Please go through [this link-Reading Excel file using Python XLRD](http://saisyam.com/2015/12/23/reading-excel-file-using-python-xlrd/) for sample codes for reading data from excel files in python.

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Hi, it is running now! (at least I think) but now I am getting 'Permission error:  Errno[13]: permission denied. How can I solve this error??

Comment: Try `pip install --user xlrd` to install packages to your home directory rather than the system

Comment: if you are getting permission problem in installing xlrd with pip try sudo pip install xlrd if you are using linux.

Comment: Hi, I used the comment of @Ev. Kounis (above comment) to run the module  but I get this error Errno[13] and I am using windows.